# How to train Faster R-CNN (TensorRT) on my dataset for NVIDIA Jetson Nano

Tags: artificial-intelligence, faster-rcnn, tensorrt

I followed the tutorial with the "faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco" but it doesn't work with my "NVIDIA Jetson nano". I would like to know which model of  FasterRCNN can work with my hardware.

Answer (score 0):

If you are after Faster RCNN based object detector for Jetson, then you might try [Nvidia Transfer Learning Toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/transfer-learning-toolkit). It looks very promising for faster deployment. At least to me.

Full documentation is [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/metropolis/TLT/tlt-getting-started-guide/index.html#requirements).

Comment: I don't have a problem with learning(I train the model on my deskup and make inference on Jetson Nano). I have a problem with inference, the model is actually very big for my Jetson nano. and I have a OOM problem. and wen it run it take at lest 3 minute for one picture

Comment: How are you doing the inference on Jetson? What env and file are you using?

Comment: I am usin TensorFlow, i also use TF-TRT. in python3

Comment: try using tensorrt for the inference